# how to set a bunch of variables depending on one condition in elisp?

Tags: lisp, elisp

Suppose I want to set the values of `bar` and `baz` depending on one condition, which is the same in both cases, say the value of `foo`.  Using the `let` special form, I do something like this

```
(let ((bar (if foo 1 2))
      (baz (if foo 3 4)))
  ... )
```

While the above program is correct, it seems a little strange as it checks the value of `foo` twice.  Is there an idiomatic expression one can use in such cases to avoid the double-check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needn't set the values in the let form itself. The let form creates the local bindings, after which you can set values however you so wish.

```el
(let (bar baz)
  (if foo
      (setq bar 1
            baz 2)
    (setq bar 3
          baz 4))
  ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the multiple values provided by `cl-lib.el`, the *Common Lisp extensions for Emacs*:

```
(multiple-value-bind (bar baz) 
    (if foo (values 1 3) (values 2 4))
  ...)
```

You might want to extract both cases in separate functions.

Answer (score 1):

The only answer I can think of in elisp (no multiple values) is something rather horrid like this:

```
(apply (lambda (bar baz)
         ...)
       (if foo
           (list 1 2)
         (list 3 4)))
```

This is consy in general, although obviously it need not be in good cases where you can supply literal lists.

You could wrap this in a macro: the following is such although it desperately needs some error checking (elisp is just too annoying to write for me to want to spend more time on it than this -- at least it has backquote now).

```
(defmacro plet (vars-vals &rest forms)
  `(apply (lambda ,(car vars-vals)
            ,@forms)
          ,(cadr vars-vals)))
```

And then your expression would become (using literal lists this time)

```
(plet ((bar baz) (if foo '(1 2) '(3 4)))
  ...)
```